# mysql mod security error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install mysql mod security on my debian machine, but it gives me the following error when I do this -
`apt-get install libapache-mod-security`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liblua5.1-0 mod-security-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache-mod-security liblua5.1-0 mod-security-common
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,173 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,506 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 syntax error: unknown user 'mixmaster' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> sudo apt-get remove --purge mixmaster

Or

Check for

> cat /etc/groups.default | grep mix
>   If there is a mixmaster user/group in defaults put it in the system file too
>   edit /etc/groups and put in the put in the output of *cat /etc/groups.default | grep mix* command
>   run *apt-get* again

Or

Check for

> dpkg-statoverride

This command may be of some help